# Grid not well displayed on Chrome on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, reactjs

I am using React with the react-absolute-grid component (https://github.com/jrowny/react-absolute-grid) to display a gallery of images.

If I access the web page from Chrome from my laptop(using the page resolution for mobile), the display looks well:

[image]

However, if look at the page from my phone I get all images on top of one another:

[image]

What could be the cause of the issue?
Is it `react-absolute-grid`?

Comment: are you using `chrome://inspect` ?

Comment: No, I should try that.